# Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'Calc' not found in C:\wamp64\www\OOPCalculator\includes\calc.inc.php on line 9

Tags: php

I found this code of the internet but it doesnt work i keep getting this error. Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'Calc' not found in C:\wamp64\www\OOPCalculator\includes\calc.inc.php on line 9

I dont Know Why This Is Happening But If You Could Help Me Please

```
declare(strict_types = 1);
include 'includes/class-autoload.inc.php';

$oper = $_POST["oper"];
$num2 = $_POST["num2"];
$num1 = $_POST["num1"];

$Calc = new Calc($oper, (int)$num1, (int)$num2);

try {
    echo $Calc->calculation();
}
catch (TypeError $e) {
    echo "Error!: ". $e->getMessage();
}
?>
```

```
<?php

class Calc {
    public $operater;
    public num1;
    public num2;
    
    public function __construct(string $one, int $two, int $three) {
        $this->operater = $one;
        $this->num1 = $two;
        $this->num2 = $three;

    }
    
    public function calculator() {
        switch($this->operater) {
            case 'add':
            $result = $this->num1 + $this->num2;
            return $result;
            break;
            
            case 'sub':
            $result = $this->num1 - $this->num2;
            return $result;
            break;
            
            case 'div':
            $result = $this->num1 / $this->num2;
            return $result;
            break;
            
            case 'mul':
            $result = $this->num1 * $this->num2;
            return $result;
            break;
            
            default:
            echo "Error!";
            break;
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: The autoloader is not loading the class. Could be a number of issues with it. Check your project's structure and see if it adheres to the autoloader rules.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the code of  class-autoload.inc.php

Answer (score 1):

Please check the declaration of the property in your class properly. You missed $ sign.

```
class Calc {
    public $operater;
    public $num1;
    public $num2;
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check your Autoloader it should look like this

```
    <?php
        spl_autoload_register('myAutoLoader');
        function myAutoLoader($className){
        $url = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
        if(strpos($url, 'includes') !== false){
        $path = '../classes/';
        }
        else{
        $path = './classes/';
        }
        $extension = ".class.php";
        require_once $path . $className . $extension;
        }
        ?>
```